# gdebi Dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: apt, kali-linux, 64bit, skype

I am trying to install Skype on amd64 Kali-Linux following this [tutorial](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/02/26/install-skype-in-kali-linux/). However once I got to step 4.1, `gdebi skype-install.deb`, I got this error message: `This package is uninstallable Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0` I have tried to `apt-get install libssl1.0.0` it and it said that it was up to date. Then I tried `apt-get autoremove` and then tried to `apt-get install` it again. It again said it was up to date and I again tried to use `gdebi` to no avail. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The `libssl1.0.0` package is not available anymore in stretch or sid.

You can still obtain it by downloading it from snapshot.debian.org: http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libssl1.0.0/

Be aware that there will be no security update for this package if you are installing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The missing package (`libssl1.0.0` ) doesn't exist on [Kali.repo](https://pkg.kali.org/search?package_name=libssl1.0.0) , you can install it from [debian repo](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0) as recommended [**here**](https://wiki.debian.org/skype#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22) .

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u5_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u5_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Then install skype:

```
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
gdebi skype-install.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Still says `Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian (unstable) system, libssl1.0.0 was also made unavailable, and I couldn't grab a copy of it as suggested in previous answers.

But I was able to patch the package to require libssl1.0.2 instead, which I noticed was available to me, and Skype worked just fine.

This is my patched deb: http://teamfiles.n2.gs/3bbed19f40405b7d984d5d6113c461e7/skype_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

You can do that it yourself like this:

```
# This will create a skype/ directory.
$ dpkg-deb -R skype-install.deb skype
```

Edit `skype/DEBIAN/control` using your preferred text editor and replace `libssl1.0.0` by `libssl1.0.2` (or similar version available from your package manager; but of course, if the version is too different, it probably won't work).

```
# This will create and install your patched package.
$ dpkg-deb -b skype skype/
$ sudo gdebi '<path to generated deb>'
```